# php xpath return nothing, can't undertand :s

Tags: php, xpath

I am doing some xpath, and I can't get any result,

My code:

```
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $qq = ('/html/head');
    $result_rows = $xpath->query($qq);

    var_dump ($result_object);

    echo '<br>debug begin<br>';
    foreach ($result_rows as $result_object)
    {
        echo 'for each foreach<br>';
        echo $result_object->nodeValue;
    }
    echo '<br>debug end<br>';
```

Result:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } 
debug begin

debug end
```

He doesn't step in on foreach cycle, because he's on the result there is no "for each foreach"

Result that it should be:

```
debug begin
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
debug end
```

Comment: Well, uh... You have `$result_rows` when you set the var. But you use `$result_object` for var_dump... Those are 2 different variable names.

Comment: BTW, remove the STFU `@` operator in front of `@$doc->loadHTML($html);` so you are notified if loading the files gives any problems. I think there you will find your answer.

Comment: cant remove that @, or i will get 99999 errors lol, ye, it should be var_dump ($result_rows);, its the same

Comment: see my answer below. Never just disregard errors. That's like hiding your head in the sand. Tell us what the error messages are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Remove the `@` in front of `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`
**2.** Fix the 99999 of errors (as per your comment). (read the error messages! Tell us what they are.)
**3.** Only then will `$html` actually hold html data that can then be read into a XML/DOM document.

Now you are failing in getting the HTML. And you are reading in an empty string into the XML/DOM document. And that on its turn is why your XPATH is returning empty... because the entire HTML is not there.

**edit:**
For more info why your site isn't loaded into XML/DOM, change `@$doc->loadHTML($html);` into this:

```
if (!$doc->loadHTML($html)) {
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        print_r($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Anyway, it is expecting HTML. So if you already know it's not HTML, then there is your problem.

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\lolwinrate\core\functions\general.php on line 37

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\lolwinrate\core\functions\general.php on line 37Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\lolwinrate\core\functions\general.php on line 37 loots of them

Comment: this html code is a xml http rquest, maybe it havent a format of a html page...is that? i tried on google chrome and worked...dunno

Comment: if not critical, give us the url of the page so we can see the HTML. From the PHP manual: While malformed HTML should load successfully, this function may generate E_WARNING errors when it encounters bad markup. libxml's error handling functions ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php ) may be used to handle these errors.

Comment: like i said this is a xml http request, i made my php write on a txt and uploaded via dropbox https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4765898/html.txt ### now that i notice, when i tested with google chrome, it had the full html of the page, not this portion that i uploaded...so xpath must be wrong?

Comment: Your html file has no `<html>` and no `<head>` tags... It just starts with `<div>`... So that could also be a reason why your xpath is returning empty.

Comment: ye, thats what i tought, but when xml start with random names, isnt the same?

Comment: `$qq = ('/html/head');` ... You are explicitly stating that you want a list of all `<head>` tags in all `<html>` tags... The xpath correctly returns an empty array, because there are none.

Comment: Try `$qq = ('//div');` in stead... then you will get an array with ALL `<div>` elements. If this works for you, don't forget to upvote the answer and/or check it as solved. (check the checkbox to the left of the answer)

Comment: it returned HOLY COW :DDDDDDDDDDDDD object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } thanks so much, i would pay you a dinner if i could :D but i didnt removed the @

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing out the nodeValue property of the result object you're returning, e.g:

```
foreach ($result_rows as $result_object) {
   echo $result_object->nodeValue;
}
```

OK, after the edit, I think you need to send each of the members of the DomNodeList into an array, and then loop through that array. E.g:

```
 $query_result = array();  //Set up an empty array
 foreach($result_rows as $result_object){ 
    //take results of xpath query and send to this array
    $query_result[] = $result_object-> nodeValue;
  }

 echo '<br>debug begin<br>';
 foreach ($query_result as $r){
    echo 'for each foreach<br>';
    echo $r;
  }
  echo '<br>debug end<br>';
```

Comment: thanks for asnwering but he doesnt enter on foreach, nothing changed, i was wrong, it isnt the "echo $result_object;"

Comment: what do you mean he doesn't enter on foreach?

Comment: he doesnt return the "echo 'test<br>';" that is inside of foreach, he would print it at least 1 time, so he doesnt go in, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Can you please restate or edit your original code?

Comment: what is that $result?

Comment: it's the array you send each of the members from $result_object into. I'll edit my post in a second.

Comment: damn...still the same, no results, i think i am gonna use the method of cuting strings -.-'